# How to get performance metrics for a VM in azure with power-shell and cli

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Am getting an error while running cli cmd " access denied".

```
   az monitor metrics list --resource 
   /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/yyy/providers/Micros‌​ 
   oft.Compute/virtualM‌​achines/TestVM --metric-names "Percentage CPU" -- 
   time-grain "PT1M" >> PercentageCpuData.txt
```

Comment: Do you have the right permissions? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-roles-permissions-security

Comment: yes Alex i have the appropriate access, i did check twice, i found out that my syntax was somehow incorrect. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using CLI v2 then the command has a number of incorrect parameter names, it should be:

> az monitor metrics list --resource
>   /subscriptions/subID/resourceGroups/RGName/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/machinename
>   --metric "Percentage CPU" --interval PT1M

If that still doesn't work you will need to check that you do actually have the right permissions to query this.

Comment: Thank you Sam, Yes it was syntax error, and i had my az config set json,thank you, would you also share how could i get data for a month or 15 days?

Comment: @NikNik use the start time and end time parameters, this is all in the docs - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/metrics?view=azure-cli-latest#az-monitor-metrics-list